# How to know which branch a change came from with JGit's DiffCommand?

Tags: git, jgit

I can't seem to figure out a quick and easy way to determine which tree (old or new) a given `DiffEntry` came from. In my case I'm only interested in the "outgoing" (so to speak) changes in the defect/working tree...any new "incoming" changes from the other/master branch are of no interest.

IOW, I only want the path names, versions, and change types of the files **I've changed** that aren't yet in the other/master branch...I surely don't need or want to parse the file content changes. The master branch changes will be of interest eventually, of course, but they are cluttering the programmatic use case I have.

Code snippet:

```java
AbstractTreeIterator oldTreeParser = prepareTreeParser( repository, oldBranchName );
AbstractTreeIterator newTreeParser = prepareTreeParser( repository, newBranchName );
gitInstance = new Git( repository );
List<DiffEntry> diff = gitInstance.diff().setOldTree( oldTreeParser ).setNewTree( newTreeParser ).setShowNameAndStatusOnly( true ).call();
for (DiffEntry entry : diff)
{
   // is entry from oldTree or newTree or both?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DiffEntry::getChangeType()` method to determine if a file was added, changed, or removed.

For example:

```java
switch( diffEntry.getChangeType() ) {
  case ADD:
    // file does not exist in oldBranch, file is new in newBranch
    break;
  case DELETE:
    // file did exist in oldBranch, file was deleted in newBranch
    break;
  case MODIFY:
    // file exists in oldBranch and newBranch, content was changed
    break;
  case COPY:
  case RENAME:
    // file was copied or moved to a new location
    break;
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I don't believe getChangeType() is sufficient for a MODIFY to determine which branch modified the file. And for ADD and DELETE, it's also misleading because let's say neither branch originally had part A. Then someone else on the team adds part A to the master branch. When I do a diff of my working branch with master, it thinks my branch deleted part A. Not only is a "delete" action not true, but also there seems to be no way to differentiate that case from the case where I really *did* delete part A in my branch.

Comment: So what I'm really after is WHERE the DiffEntry came from...the old branch, or the new branch, or both. Or if DiffCommand cannot determine that for some reason, perhaps another API approach that can? Something that's not a big performance hit, preferably, which parsing diff output seems like it would be (may be dealing with dozens, hundreds, or even thousands of files sometimes).

Comment: To me, there seems to be a mismatch in your understanding of some of the Git concepts (e.g. what is a branch, what is a diff). To my knowledge, the change type ADD denotes an actual addition and DELETE denotes an actual deletion. If you have doubt, please come back with a test case to proof or disprove your assumption.

Comment: It's quite easy to prove. I have two branches, ZB05911 (the current checked out branch in the example output below) and ZB07675. In the former, I added a new file, new1.txt. In the latter, I also added a new file, new2.txt. I also modified part "clrcrfmt.asm" in the former, and part "clrcxtrc.asm" in the latter.

<pre>
C:\GitClones\HBLD260>git diff --name-status ZB07675
M       clrcrfmt.asm
M       clrcxtrc.asm
A       new1.txt
D       new2.txt
</pre>

Not only is there no way to know which modification was done in which branch, it also thinks "new2.txt" is a deleted file.

Comment: Sorry, but can't read your comment. Furthermore, I don't have your repository, please post code that builds, executes and verifies the scenario if you want others to be able to follow your reasoning.

Comment: Well, it's really as trivial as this: add a new part to one branch, add another new part to another branch. Diff the branches. One part shows as a Add, the other as an Delete. Not only is the Delete not technically correct, it's also not possible to differentiate the case where someone else added a part, or I deleted it (just from Diff's status output). They both are listed as a Delete action. Same is true for Modify actions...I don't know which branch modified the part just from the DiffEntry data. I think only with Adds can I be sure that *my* branch added the part.

Comment: So I suspect I will have to take each Modify and Delete DiffEntry and do further digging into my branch's history to determine if the "new" object ID exists. If it does, I should know that change was done by my branch. If not, I know it was done by the other branch and I can ignore it. Not sure offhand the quickest way to dig that info out yet, but maybe LogCommand or BlameCommand will be of use.

Comment: Actually, Add has the same problem. If the other branch deleted a part, diff output show it as an Add action. So I'm going to have to analyze every single entry.